# AbstractList<E> - Difference between return types of add(int index, E element), add(E e) etc?

Tags: java

The methods `addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)` and `add(E e)` return a `boolean` to inform that an element has been added successfully. On the other hand, `add(int index, E element)` does not.

Why is it like this? How will I come to know if the element could be added or not ?

Comment: You'd have to ask whomever wrote that code as to why they elected to do that.

Comment: @Makoto - please see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add(E)` is a member of `Collection`. For some kinds of collections -- `Set`, which guarantees uniqueness,  especially -- sometimes adding an element can "fail" in a nonsurprising way, because the element was already in the collection. The boolean return value is useful in that case.

`add(int, E)`, on the other hand, is a member of `List`, and adding an element to a list will never fail in this way -- a `List`, by definition, can contain duplicate elements.

`addAll(int, Collection<E>)` is a little harder. It is a member of `List`, so by definition, the additions won't be rejected. The Javadoc says that is returns true "if this list changed as a result of the call." I suppose if the argument is an empty collection, it could return false.  This doesn't seem very useful.

But note that there's an `addAll(Collection<E>)` in `Collection`, and that can return `false` when all the added elements are duplications and the collection is a `Set`. So I imagine the `List` method returns `boolean` because the `Collection` method does -- for symmetry, not out of any real need.

Comment: yep. but `addAll(int, Collection)` is kind of odd though. it could return void instead of boolean.

Comment: You commented before I was all through typing :)